# How can I route all calls starting with string api to their handlers in an express middleware

Tags: express, express-router

I have a express app.js with typical

```
app.get('/path1', (req, res => {}) 
app.get('/path2', (req, res => {}) 
app.get('/path3', (req, res => {})
```

now I want to catch all routes, starting with api such as below and redirect them to their corresponding handler in express but not sure how to achieve that

```
/api/path1 
/api/path2 
/api/path3
```

I' assuming i can have a catch all api as below

```
app.all('/api/*', function (request, response, next) { //in a server.js file 
       //how can i call the corresponding paths here?? 
       // looking for something to do forward to current-route.replace('api','') 
       // or something like that 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a [router-level middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router) could solve your problem:

```
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/path1', (req, res => {});
router.get('/path2', (req, res => {});
router.get('/path3', (req, res => {});

app.use('/api', router);
```

**Update:**

Use [redirect](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.redirect) (not that much of a difference to your current solution; not tested):

```
app.all('/api/*', (request, response) => res.redirect(request.url.replace('/api', '')));
```

Comment: sorry maybe i should had been more clear, trying to run both express and react from the same port and wanted to send non api calls to  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))

Comment: actually yes,  I can use this in combination with app router! thank you

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, please let me know if there is a better way

```
app.all('/api/*', function (request, response, next) {
    request.url = request.url.replace('/api','');
    next();  
})
```